# Удалить содержимое всех HTML таблиц, используя команду sed

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, sed

У меня есть html текст, и команда sed, которая по регулярному выражению должна удалять контейнеры table:

```
sed -e '/<[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee].*>/,/<\/[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee]>/d'
```

Команда работает отлично, если тег table расположен в начале строки:

```
<HTML> 
<P>
<TABLE BORDER=0> 
<TR><TH></TH><TH>Дата</TH></TR> 
<TR><TD></TD><TD>10.12.1989</TD></TR> 
<TR><TD></TD><TD>11.11.1977</TD></TR> 
</TABLE>
<P>
</HTML>
```

становится:

```
<HTML> 
<P>
<P>
</HTML>
```

Но если перед открывающимся тегом table, или после закрывающегося тега table есть другой текст:

```
<HTML> 
<P>
<img src=""><TABLE BORDER=0> 
<TR><TH></TH><TH>Дата</TH></TR> 
<TR><TD></TD><TD>10.12.1989</TD></TR> 
<TR><TD></TD><TD>11.11.1977</TD></TR> 
</TABLE><img src="">
<P>
</HTML>
```

то удаление контейнера работает некорректно (удаляется этот лишний текст кроме таблицы):

```
<HTML> 
<P>
<P>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохим решением было выбрать Sed для решения этой задачи. Функционал регулярных выражений крайне ограничен. Вы можете попробовать решить задачу так:

```
cat test.html | tr '\n' '\f' | sed 's/<table>.*<\/table>//gi' | tr '\f' '\n'
```

Или даже так:

```
sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -re 's/<table>.*<\/table>//gi' test.html
```

Какое бы решение Вы ни выбрали- Вы натолкнетесь на то, что если в тексте будет две таблицы, то будет удалено все от первого `<table>` до последнего `</table>` и жадность эту Вы победить не сможете.
Если же в тексте всего одна таблица, то смело используйте Sed :)

---

Правильным решением будет использовать Perl:

```
perl -0pe 's/<table>.*?<\/table>//gis' test.html
```

## UPDATE

**Раз это учебное задание**
Значит можно смело применять Sed- ведь простые и правильные пути смарщивают нос преподавателей :)

```
sed -re 's/<\/?table[^>]>/\n\1\n/gi' test.html | sed -e '/<[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee].*>/,/<\/[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee]>/d'
```

Будут добавлены лишние переносы строк, если `<table>` или `</table>` были в начале или конце строки, но семантику HTML это не ломает. При желании можно избавиться и от этих лишних переносов строк.

Comment: Спасибо большое. К решению на PERL я дошел, но преподаватель начал крутить носом. Ваше решение отлично подходит.
Могу ли я поинтересоваться, какой подход можно еще использовать для корректного решения задачи, кроме sed и perl?

Comment: Спасибо большое за разьяснение.